# java treeset throwing illegalArgumentException: key out of range

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, treeset

I've stripped down the code to reproduce an example which throws the error:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(
            Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
    NavigableSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>();
    set2 = set.tailSet("c", false);
    set2.addAll(set.headSet("b", true));
    System.out.println(set2);
  }
}
```

The aim of the code is to implement some sort of rollover when retrieving subsets of the set. E.g. in the case above, I want all elements from c [exclusive] to b [inclusive]. I noticed that if I comment out the tailSet() or headSet() lines, the rest of the code works well. However, when I have both lines, I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key out of range

Comment: Maybe you could iterate on it and do it manually?

Comment: +1 for a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(
                Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
        NavigableSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>();
        set2.addAll(set.tailSet("c", false));
        set2.addAll(set.headSet("b", true));
        System.out.println(set2);
  }
```

When you do

```
set2 = set.tailSet("c", false);
```

you actually lose the reference to the new `TreeSet` that you created and get the `SortedSet` that `set.tailSet` returns.

Comment: +1 for "lose the reference to the new TreeSet...get the SortedSet that set.tailSet returns". Not sure how I missed that. I've done few tests to confirm that the error arises because I'm trying to add Strings that are <= "b" to a subset which should only contain Strings > "c". Saved one line by using NavigableSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>(set.tailSet("c", false)); Thanks!